# I can't restore tablespace. ORA-01539: tablespace '' is not online

Tags: oracle, backup

I try to create my first database backup. But it doesn't work. I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks in advance.

Backup tablespace:

```
BACKUP TABLESPACE USERS FORMAT 'c:\FRA\users%u';
```

My created backup tablespace:

```
BS Key  Type LV Size       Device Type Elapsed Time Completion Time
------- ---- -- ---------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
5       Full    150.32M    DISK        00:00:02     28-NOV-20
        BP Key: 5   Status: AVAILABLE  Compressed: NO  Tag: TAG20201128T220319
        Piece Name: C:\FRA\USERS05VGMFT7
  List of Datafiles in backup set 5
  File LV Type Ckp SCN    Ckp Time  Abs Fuz SCN Sparse Name
  ---- -- ---- ---------- --------- ----------- ------ ----
  7       Full 17446796   28-NOV-20              NO    C:\NAUCZANIE\ORADATA\WWWOR\USERS01.DBF
```

I tried to restore tablespace and I got an error.

```
RMAN> RUN{
2> SQL 'ALTER TABLESPACE USERS OFFLINE';
3> RESTORE TABLESPACE USER;
4> RECOVER TABLESPACE USERS;
5> SQL 'ALTER TABLESPACE USERS ONLINE';
6> }

sql statement: ALTER TABLESPACE USERS OFFLINE
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03009: failure of sql command on default channel at 11/28/2020 22:11:18
ORA-01539: tablespace '' is not online
RMAN-11003: failure during parse/execution of SQL statement: ALTER TABLESPACE USERS OFFLINE
ORA-01539: tablespace 'USERS' is not online
```

Comment: why do you restore USER (singular), but then recover USERS (plural)?  Why are you taking the TS offline?  It also appears that you are trying to backup into space that is supposed to be used by the FRA, but you are not using the FRA mechanism.  This will cause you to consume space from the FRA without the FRA knowing about it and thus overstating the space available to the FRA.

Comment: This looks surprisingly the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65055733/restore-tablespace-users-doesnt-work-oracle-backup